# 2 window.parent.onscroll calls on page do not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have an HTML page with 2 iframes within it. I want each iframe to display the Y scroll offset of the **parent** window. One iframe works on page load, the other does not.

The parent HTML page just has the iframe embeds. Here is the code running in the iframe:

```
function run(){
    document.write("<div id='scrollY' style='float:left;'></div><br>");
    scrollY = 'no';
    document.getElementById("scrollY").innerHTML = scrollY;
    window.parent.onscroll = function(){
        scrollY = window.parent.pageYOffset;
        document.getElementById("scrollY").innerHTML = scrollY;
    }
}
run();
```

The result on load and a scroll downwards will display something like:

```
iframe1 = 100
iframe2 = no
```

Can I only call `window.parent.onscroll` once? This doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in both frames, `window.parent` makes reference to the same `window` object, and you are setting the `onscroll` property/event on the same object, twice. This means that the second time around you set the `window.parent.onscroll` property, you're actually overwriting the first attempt to set the event, and you're overwriting it with the second frame's `window.document` object, which is why it only updates the contents of the elements in the second frame.

**To overcome this issue, you can simply just use `addEventListener` instead of `onscroll`:**

http://jsfiddle.net/x046o0p7/

```
function run() {
    document.write("<div id='scrollY' style='float:left;'></div><br>");
    scrollY = 'no';
    document.getElementById("scrollY").innerHTML = scrollY;
    window.parent.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        scrollY = window.parent.pageYOffset;
        document.getElementById("scrollY").innerHTML = scrollY;
    });
}
```

`addEventListener` allows you to set multiple events of the same type for the same element, while the `.onstuff`  listeners don't.